# Windows - create venv to python3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Machine: Windows10 with python 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9 installed.

The error when I create a new project and try to set up an environment:

```
~/path $ mkdir project
~/path $ cd project
~/path/project $ python -V
Python 3.7.7
~/path/project $ python3.8 -m venv .
bash: python3.8: command not found
```

How to set up a new project with a chosen python version please?

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana Yes, thanks! `py -3.8 -m venv .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`py -3.8 -m venv .` works for me.
The link @AmilaMGunawardana provided covers all sorts of scenarios.

Comment: what is `py`? ...